# I can't post to google?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code for a small program where you put the keyword, choosing the search engine and then pressing "Search" button to search. But google don't leave me to POST. What else I can do?

EDIT: Yahoo and Bing works fine.

ERROR

```
405. That’s an error.

The request method POST is inappropriate for the URL 
/search?q=computer. That’s all we know.
```

HTML

```
<form name="search" action="" method="Post" onSubmit="redirect()">
<input type="text" name="keyword"><br />
Google<input type="radio" name="ch" checked>
Yahoo!<input type="radio" name="ch">
Bing<input type="radio" name="ch"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var searchengine=[
"http://google.com/search?q=",
"http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=",
"http://bing.com/search?q="
];

function redirect()
{
    var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("ch");
    for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x++) {
        if (radioButtons[x].checked)
        {
            document.search.action = searchengine[x] + document.search.keyword.value;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But google don't leave me to POST. What else I can do?

Use `GET` rather than `POST` in your form, or just assign the relevant URL to `window.location`.

Here's an example of the latter. Some other changes:

- Added some `label`s.
- Changed how you're matching up the selected radio button and the `searchengine` to make it more robust/maintainable.
- Changed the name of the search form. Since this gets dumped on the `window` object I avoid simple words like "search".
- Properly encoded the keyword (you must encode URI parameters).

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ezerug/1) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/ezerug/1/edit)

HTML:

```
<form name="searchForm" action="" method="GET" onSubmit="return doSearch()">
<input type="text" name="keyword">
  <br>
  <label>Google<input type="radio" name="ch" value="google" checked></label>
  <label>Yahoo!<input type="radio" name="ch" value="yahoo"></label>
  <label>Bing<input type="radio" name="ch" value="bing"></label>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var searchengine = {
  "google": "http://google.com/search?q=",
  "yahoo": "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=",
  "bing": "http://bing.com/search?q="
};
function doSearch() {
  var frm, index, cb;

  frm = document.searchForm;
  if (frm && frm.ch) {
    if (frm.ch) {
      for (index = 0; index < frm.ch.length; ++index) {
        cb = frm.ch[index];
        if (cb.checked) {
          window.location = searchengine[cb.value] +
            encodeURIComponent(frm.keyword.value);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return false; // Cancels form submission
}
```

Comment: @Loclip: `GET` would work if the form fields were correct. Specifically, your `keyword` field would need to be `q` and you'd have to remove `q` from the URL you're submitting to, since Google expects `q` to be the search term.

Comment: Oh, I see... But its easier just to use window.location

Comment: @Loclip: In this case, since you're relying on JavaScript anyway, yeah. :-) It would be possible to do this without JavaScript (with largely the same UI) using clever CSS visibility selectors, but the user would have to choose the search engine before typing the keyword (as we'd have to show/hide different forms containing the keyword field). A bit OTT, probably. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`"http:google.com/search?q="`, is not formatted properly..

try `"http://google.com/search?q="`

Comment: While true, we can tell from the error he's getting that this isn't the problem.

Comment: I just copied wrong thing... its fixed in original... its not the problem